# Login Page, want to check for existing users

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, authentication

For my registration page, I want to check for existing users before adding a new user to avoid duplicate usernames. For some reason, after I check if an existing username exists in the database, it does not run any of the code afterwards.

```js
app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  var newuser = false;

  db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?;", [username], (err, result) => {
      
    if (err) {
      res.send({err: err})
    }

    if (result.length == 0) {
      newuser = true;
      console.log(newuser + "one")
    }
  })

    if (newuser) {
    console.log(newuser + "two")
    bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
      if (err)
      console.log(err)
    
      db.query(
        "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)",
        [username, hash],
        (err, result) => {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
          }
      )
    })
  }
})
```

In this example, the only output I get is "trueone" ... meaning that it evaluated result.length to 0 and set newuser = true.

Comment: `if (newuser) ` is outside the query callback and therefore runs before the first query has completed

Comment: Your 'SELECT & INSERT' method leads directly to a race condition. A better way to do this is to set a UNIQUE index on the username column in your database and then just INSERT. The database will prevent duplicates and tell you if you've tried to insert one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are not waiting to the result of the first select. You can use async function or move the if(new user) condition into the select callback.